# Error while building TensoRT engine from Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, nvidia, tensorrt

I am converting a Keras model to tensor RT.

First I converted the Keras model to a TensorFlow frozen graph (.pb).

Then converted the Frozen graph to UFF file Terminal output given below:-

```
    UFF Version 0.6.5
=== Automatically deduced input nodes ===
[name: "input"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
]
=========================================

=== Automatically deduced output nodes ===
[name: "concatenate_1/concat"
op: "ConcatV2"
input: "conv2d_25/truediv"
input: "conv2d_26/BiasAdd"
input: "concatenate_1/concat/axis"
attr {
  key: "N"
  value {
    i: 2
  }
}
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tidx"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
]
==========================================

Using output node concatenate_1/concat
Converting to UFF graph
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
WARNING:tensorflow:From ../../uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py:179: The name tf.AttrValue is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.AttrValue instead.

Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: PlaceholderWithDefault yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/keras_learning_phase as custom op: PlaceholderWithDefault
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_1/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_2/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_3/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_4/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_5/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_6/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_7/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_8/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_9/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_10/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_11/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_12/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_13/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_14/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_15/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_16/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_17/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_18/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_19/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_20/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_21/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_22/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Merge yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/Merge as custom op: Merge
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_23/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_4 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_3 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_2 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch_1 as custom op: Switch
Warning: No conversion function registered for layer: Switch yet.
Converting batch_normalization_24/cond/FusedBatchNorm/Switch as custom op: Switch
Warning: keepdims is ignored by the UFF Parser and defaults to True
Warning: keepdims is ignored by the UFF Parser and defaults to True
DEBUG [../../uff/converters/tensorflow/converter.py:96] Marking ['concatenate_1/concat'] as outputs
No. nodes: 511
UFF Output written to /home/kingashar/tensorRT/Models/wpod/tf_model.uff
```

As you can see the UFF converter has set the output node to ['concatenate_1/concat'].

Now when I run code to build a trt engine I get these errors.

```
    [TensorRT] ERROR: UffParser: Validator error: batch_normalization_24/cond/Merge: Unsupported operation _Merge
Building TensorRT engine, this may take a few minutes...
[TensorRT] ERROR: Network must have at least one output
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buildTRTengine.py", line 32, in <module>
    buf = trt_engine.serialize()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

**Because TRT cannot detect an output layer it is not able to serialize the engine.
Any Idea on how to solve this??**

**Also, I have multiple Merge layers in my graph which are not supported by TRT. 
What should I replace it with so that the engine gets build successfully?**

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue of support for the layer you are using. I'm not savvy in Keras but it seems Merge is like a concat?

The list of supported operators for TF layers can be found here in the [support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-support-matrix/index.html), also check the picture:
[image]

As you can see Merge is not there, with TF and TF2 I've seen that there are multiple issues while doing the conversion, since layer support lacks a little. Try converting it to `.onnx`. I've used it to convert multiple networks and layer support is a bit broader.

Or you could write your own layer conversion, but that'll take quite the effort.

Also can you post the layer architecture? Maybe I'm confusing the layers you are trying to use.